# Identify Unique JS Object on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a little hard to describe but here goes. I'm building a page that looks something like the back end to Azure where the user chooses from a menu on the left that loads an item, call it AllUsers for now, to the right of it. From AllUsers there are options for that item and some of those might load another to the left of it, we will call that User. From User you could open more items to the right.

I have it setup nicely with a JS object something like

```
var AdminPage=function(){
    this.con="../controllers/admin/admin_con.php";
    this.pageName=null;
    this.childPage=null;
    this.page=null;

    this.deleteItem=function(){
        //Recursively deletes pages to the right
        if(this.childPage){
            this.childPage.delete();
            this.childPage=null;
        }
        if(this.page){
            this.page.remove();
        }
        return this;
    }

    this.add=function(pageData){
        if(this.childPage){
            this.deleteItem();
        }

        this.childPage=new AdminPage();
        this.childPage.getPage(pageData);

        return this;
    };

    this.getPage=function(pageData){
        var that=this;

        this.pageName=pageData.page;

        $.post(this.con, pageData,
            function(data,status){
                if(status==='success'){
                    $("#rightCol").append(data);
                    var num=$("#rightCol").children().length;
                    that.page=$("#rightCol").children()[num-1];
                    eval(pageData.page+"=that");
                }
            }
        );

        return this;
    };

}
```

So each time a page is added it creates a new instance of the object for that item to work with. If that item is removed it recursively removes all items to the right of it as well.

The line "eval(pageData.page+"=that");" and yes I now that eval is evil and have read all about it, creates a new variable name from the name of the item that has been added. That item say the User item then uses that variable when even it needs to call on its instance of the script. This all works mostly perfectly.

Where it fails is if the User item opens another, call it Connections that shows all the connections for that user. I then want to be able to click on a connection and have it open another User item, this works as it should how ever the problem lies when the second User item is opened and creates a new instance of the AdminPage because the same script has just loaded and has the same name it over writes the JS variable from the previous one. Then then affects several things. If you close one of them it closes both for instance and if you close the first that was loaded it should close what is to the right of it however the childPage property is now empty so that doesn't work.

So now for the question..

Is there a better way to handle creating the variables or is there an all around better way all together that will not cause this problem at all?

Can I get around using the Evil eval and make everything right with the world?

Thanks for any suggestions that you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found an answer to the problem but I still don't like it much.

I have generated a unique id and appended it to the end of the name of the script that I was using as the variable.

Issues with this method is it is still using eval and now I have to pass the variable round trip when getting the new item so that I can use php to inject the variable name into the page.

Not perfect and there has to be a better way.

Here is the updated add function

```
this.add=function(pageData){
    if(this.childPage){
        this.deleteChildren();
    }

    this.childPage=new AdminPage();

    this.childPage.id=pageData.page+"_"+(Math.floor(Math.random() * (999999999 - 100000000 + 1)) + 100000000);
    eval(this.childPage.id+"=this.childPage");

    this.childPage.getPage(pageData);

    return this;
};
```